# Getting Started With AngularJS and IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intellij-idea

Hello I'm trying to learn Angular.js and IntelliJ IDEA. I was wondering can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to do a simple hello world example from a book, but it's not working for me in the IDE. I'm not sure whats really sure why it's not working, but to start the project I downloaded the AngularJS plugin. I went to the project location using the command line and did bower install angular, and copy and pasted the example from the ng-book for hello world, but it's not working for me. I tried to add the path to the html and it still didn't work. Can someone help me out?

[image: My Editor Screenshot]

[image: What's in the brower]

Answer (score 0):

you can see the working version of your work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.15/angular.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="exampleModule">
<input ng-model="dynamicName" type="text" placeholder="write your name here">
    <p>Hello {{dynamicName}} !</p>

  <script>
    angular.module('exampleModule', []);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I dont know is you address angular correctly or not, but you need a module for your code, even an empty one like what I've just put in the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 - Move the ng-app directive to body tag of the page.

Option 2 - It could be possible that browser is rendering a cached page which had errors. Can you force refresh to GET the latest files? In most modern browsers user CTRL+F5.

Option 3 - Use the developer panel of the browser and force reload the page and notice any error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the file read/write permissions on your localhost file.Go to the bower_components file in your finder, right-click ->get info. Scroll down in the info window to the permissions section and change **sharing and permissions** to Everyone - Read/Write.
Then click the Cog drop down and select the option **Apply to enclosed items**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to invoke the angular file from wrong path

replace with following

```
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```